# Ubuntu Touch the first phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I am a web-developer and I really love Ubuntu. I like its design and ecosystem. Sometimes it slow or laggy, but I can usually solve problems myself, or they're due to my hardware.

I've been using an Android phone and for me it is becoming too slow for email, skype, hangouts etc so I decided to change my phone.

I want a smartphone which I will not want to reflash or use some custom firmware on, so I want an Ubuntu phone.

I want to know, what will be the cost, release date, and specifications of the Ubuntu Phone?

I am working on Ubuntu Touch Apps to integrate social networks from ex-USSR countries like Facebook is integrated - as a result it will be comfortable to use for Russians, Ukrainians and others.

For me my smartphone is not a toy - it is a work instrument, and I want the same OS on my work Laptop and smartphone.

Comment: I suggest having a look at this page [Operators and OEMs](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/operators-and-oems) for specs. Use the links at the top of the page to explore the rest.

Comment: Thank you @BiggJJ

I looked at it and it is good for me - may be anyone know the nearest price for the **Ubuntu Phone**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu Phone is not a specific phone, but an operating system to be run on phones. Right now, in development, the official reference models are Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4. You'll be able to install Ubuntu Phone on either of those, but keep in mind it's not meant to be ready for the public yet – and it will require you to unlock the phone.

As of now, there are no official statements from hardware manufacturers intending to ship Ubuntu Phone on their devices by default. Because of that, it's impossible to say anything about prices, or when to expect them. I would, however, not expect any phones to hit the market until spring/summmer 2014. After all, that's when the next LTS is released, and I would assume that hardware manufacturers would want long-term support for their devices. That is pure speculation, of course.

Comment: Thank you @Jo-Erlend Schinstad
If I understood you right - no one nows the price for Ubuntu Phone, because we do not have any information from manufacturers who will build them.

Anyway I will wait for Ubuntu Phone - and my next smartphone will be Ubuntu Phone.

I do not want any smartphone with the other OS.

I'll make usefull applications for it - to make opportunity to use skype, hangouts, emails, social messangers etc...

Comment: Ubuntu Phone will be free. You can download and run it on your phone now, if you want to. But which models will come with Ubuntu Phone preinstalled is unknown. Currently, Ubuntu Phone means Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4.

Answer (score 3):

As of now (July 2015) there are three devices available to the general public with Ubuntu Touch already installed.

You can find a list including features and pricing here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/devices